# Azure Data Factory Pipeline to copy multiple tables fails

Tags: database, azure, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory

My first Post, Sorry in advance if i'm doing anything wrong

I've followed the instructions per the Microsoft Document below and created a data factory to copy multiple tables' data from an On-Prem database to Azure database.

[here](http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-bulk-copy)

The Pipeline fails with the following error :

```
PipelineName      : GetTableListAndTriggerCopyData
LastUpdated       : 3/20/2020 10:16:42 AM
Parameters        : {}
RunStart          : 3/20/2020 10:16:10 AM
RunEnd            : 3/20/2020 10:16:42 AM
DurationInMs      : 32430
Status            : Failed
Message           : Operation on target TriggerCopy failed:Operation on target IterateSQLTables failed: Activity failed because an inner activity failed
```

Json data for both pipelines are as below:

***1st Pipeline IterateAndCopySQLTables***

```
{
"name": "IterateAndCopySQLTables",
"properties": {
    "activities": [
        {
            "name": "IterateSQLTables",
            "type": "ForEach",
            "typeProperties": {
                "isSequential": "false",
                "items": {
                    "value": "@pipeline().parameters.tableList",
                    "type": "Expression"
                },
                "activities": [
                    {
                        "name": "CopyData",
                        "description": "Copy data from On Prem SQL database to Azure SQL database",
                        "type": "Copy",
                        "inputs": [
                            {
                                "referenceName": "OnPremSourceDataset",
                                "type": "DatasetReference"
                            }
                        ],
                        "outputs": [
                            {
                                "referenceName": "AzureSinkDataset",
                                "type": "DatasetReference",
                                "parameters": {
                                    "SinkTableName": "[@{item().TABLE_NAME}]"
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "typeProperties": {
                            "source": {
                                "type": "SqlSource",
                                "sqlReaderQuery": "SELECT * FROM dbo.[@{item().TABLE_NAME}]"
                            },
                            "sink": {
                                "type": "AzureSqlSink",
                                "preCopyScript": "TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.[@{item().TABLE_NAME}]"
                            }

                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "parameters": {
        "tableList": {
            "type": "Array"
        }
    }
}
}
```

***2nd PipeLine : GetTableListAndTriggerCopyData***

```
{
"name":"GetTableListAndTriggerCopyData",
"properties":{
    "activities":[
        { 
            "name": "LookupTableList",
            "description": "Retrieve the table list from On Prem SQL database",
            "type": "Lookup",
            "typeProperties": {
                "source": {
                    "type": "SqlSource",
                    "sqlReaderQuery": "SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' and TABLE_NAME in ('Brd','Loc')"
                },
                "dataset": {
                    "referenceName": "OnPremSourceDataset",
                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                },
                "firstRowOnly": false
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "TriggerCopy",
            "type": "ExecutePipeline",
            "typeProperties": {
                "parameters": {
                    "tableList": {
                        "value": "@array(activity('LookupTableList').output.value)",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    }
                },
                "pipeline": {
                    "referenceName": "IterateAndCopySQLTables",
                    "type": "PipelineReference"
                },
                "waitOnCompletion": true
            },
            "dependsOn": [
                {
                    "activity": "LookupTableList",
                    "dependencyConditions": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
}
```

Comment: This may be with concurrency I had a similar yet non descriptive error when moving flat files (which i later moved to Databricks!) have a look into the settings for concurrency

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i will research that.

Comment: @Samy999 Any troubleshooting for concurrency? Any conclusion?

Comment: @JayGong I played around with the code a bit and it's definitely something with the Syntax:
Here : @array(activity('LookupTableList').output.value)
and here : [@{item().TABLE_NAME}]

coze i replaced those parameters with the actual table name and it worked.

Comment: @Samy999 So you mean it works unless you set the static variable?

Comment: @JayGong It works only when I hardcode the tabla names in the script
so instead of [@{item().TABLE_NAME}] , I use (BRANDS) as the table name.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for ur comments.

The issue was in (GetTableListAndTriggerCopyData)

"value": "@array(activity('LookupTableList').output.value)",
 Is wrong, the correct syntax is :
"value": "@activity('LookupTableList').output.value)",